# Классификация ближайших соседей, формула нормализации данных. Поиск среднего и среднеквадратичного отклонений

Tags: python, python-3.x, классификация

Решаю задание из летней практики. Ранее не работал с такими задачами вообще, поэтому нужна помощь

В общем, хочу для начала узнать - правильно ли я нормализировал столбцы.

**По заданию преподавателя нужно было сделать следующее**:
*выполнить нормализацию каждого столбца (кроме последнего) матрицы X.*

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([
[4, 4],
[3, 3],
[5, 3],
[2, 3],
[5, 5],
[3, 2],
[2, 4],
[4, 5],
[5, 4],
[2, 2]])

sub_X = X[:, 0:-1] # Хранит часть матрицы X без последнего столбца.

# Нормализация, по формуле которую я нашел в гугле - X_norm = X-X_min / X_max-X_min
normalized_X = (sub_X - np.min(sub_X, axis=0)) / (np.max(sub_X, axis=0) - np.min(sub_X, axis=0))
```

Я не уверен, что формула найденная мной является верной, поэтому решил перестраховаться и спросить насчет этого тоже.

**Следующее что я должен выполнить по заданию**: *зная параметры среднего и среднеквадратического отклонения по каждому столбцу sub_X, выполнить нормализацию объекта obj*

Я прошерстил довольно много статей на habr, а так же википедию, но все еще не нашел (не понял) что является *средним отклонением* (находил только среднеквадратичное отклонение, возможно это одно и тоже) был бы рад услышать ответ.

**Теперь перейду к основному вопросу**: *как найти это самое среднее и среднеквадратичное отклонение? (Являются ли значения моей нормализированной матрицы X этими отклонениями)?*

Буду благодарен за любое объяснение / помощь с кодом если она понадобится

Answer (score 1):

1. Начнем с "основного вопроса" - `"как найти это самое среднее и среднеквадратичное отклонение?"`. Еще раз читаем: найти СРЕДНЕЕ и найти СРЕДНЕКВАДРАТИЧНОЕ ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ.

Уж не знаю, где и что вы изучаете, но что такое среднее - вообще-то говоря учат в школе. В классе этак в пятом. При работе c numpy можете использовать соответствующий метод .mean(). Для вашего примера это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
mn1=X[:,0].mean()
mn2=X[:,1].mean()
```

Но если очень хочется, то можете и посчитать самостоятельно, по формуле среднего (за одно - и что такое среднее значение вспомните):

```
av1=X[:,0].sum()/len(X)
av2=X[:,1].sum()/len(X)
```

Результат тождественен. Можете проверить.

Что такое среднеквадратичное отклонение - это тоже изучают на первом семестре курса теории вероятностей и мат.статистике. По сути - это корень квадратный среднего значения квадратов отклонения значений ряда от его же среднего. Т.е. опять можете посчитать самостоятельно:

```
std1=(((X[:,0]-av1)**2).sum()/len(X))**0.5
std2=(((X[:,1]-av1)**2).sum()/len(X))**0.5
```

Опять-же, о нас позаботились создатели numpy и создали готовый метод:

```
std1=X[:,0].std()
std2=X[:,1].std()
```

2. Вопрос второй -`"Являются ли значения моей нормализированной матрицы X этими отклонениями"` -  разумеется нет. Это совсем другие сущности.
3. Вопрос третий - Нормализация.
   Дело в том, что нормализация бывает разной. По какой формуле вы должны считать в вашем случае - это должен вам был сказать преподаватель (явно в задании или неявно, на занятии, когда объяснял, что такое нормализация). Если вы этот материал упустили -  то можете его легко найти в интернет, например: https://wiki.loginom.ru/articles/data-normalization.html
   и выбрать тот, о котором вам рассказывали. Ну, или какой вам больше понравился.
4. Вопрос четвертый. `"зная параметры среднего и среднеквадратического отклонения ... выполнить нормализацию"`. Ну, объединив ответы на предыдущие вопросы, ответ получается практически автоматически.
5. Вопрос пятый. Причем тут `"Классификация ближайших соседей"` -  вообще загадка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хоть и в довольно грубой форме (по моему мнению). 
Начну с того что никакого лекционного материала для решения этого задания нам предоставлено не было (за исключением методички, содержащей пример как работает классификация (по мнению моего преподавателя)).
Продолжая хочу сказать, что сейчас в школах,  в пятом классе не проходят отклонения от слова совсем. Если вы хотели назвать среднее арифметическое - средним отклонением, то хорошо (дополню тем, что для меня это по-прежнему среднее арифметическое, а не среднее отклонение)

Comment: Именно по мнению моего преподавателя это является задачей на классификацию, насколько оно соответствует данной теме - судить вам. Я в этом новичок, поэтому спорить не буду.
По-факту вопрос был задан из-за слишком размытого условия решения задачи. Ну в этом я не виноват ибо шаги и само задание создавал не я. 
За остальную информацию благодарю(хоть уже и решил проблемы) - за статью о нормализации отдельно. Поисковик не выдавал мне подобных при моих запросах.

Comment: @Mono- Это не я захотел "назвать среднее арифметическое-средним отклонением". Это вы не поняли задание и вместо "среднего (арифметического)" начали придумывать себе "среднее отклонение".  Именно среднее арифметическое требуется в той задаче, которая перед вами поставлена.  И если вы действительно прочитали информацию по ссылке, которую я вам дал, то безусловно обнаружили, что именно эти две величины - "среднее  АРИФМЕТИЧЕСКОЕ" и "среднеквадратичное отклонение" необходимы для выполнения нормализации.  И кстати -  "не понял что является средним отклонением " -  это ваш вопрос.